# I have configured HMTL web page onto IIS server. Main page loaded properly. But sublinks not loading, getting http 500 internal server error

Tags: python, flask, iis, proxy, proxy-server

I have configured HMTL web page onto IIS server. Main page is getting loaded properly and sublinks wherever we are using only HTML files are also working fine. But the other pages where some other python functions being called are not getting loaded and receiving http 500 internal server error.

Configured iis which is working fine for main page. Also tried keeping edgerc file in default home directory.

I have debugged the code. I am running python flask code in the remote desktop and  trying to access one of the web portal. I am getting below error. Please try to help me to resolve.
Caused by Proxy error('Cannot connect to proxy', Connectionreseterror(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host')

Comment: Generic 500.0 or another error code? Keep in mind no one can see your screen, so you need to edit the question to include details. Screen shots can be used when it is difficult to describe.

Comment: We need some more details for troubleshooting: Get failed request tracing log
Enable Tracing from Windows features -> Restart IIS, open failed request tracing feature on website level -> Add -> All content -> status code(500-501) -> Finish -> Enable Tracing funcition -> reproduce Error -> Get logs at "C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles"